# How to read the list of gids a uid is associated in kernel space?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I've a Linux kernel driver which do some authentication based on gid. The driver will get uid as input. Now I need to get all gid this user is associated.

For ex:

```
$ id
uid=1313(tuser) gid=1313(tuser) groups=1313(tuser),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),124(sambashare)
```

If the drivers gets 1313 as uid, I need to read all gids i.e 1313,4,24,27,30,46,124

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

> I've a Linux kernel driver which do some authentication based on gid. The driver will get uid as input. Now I need to get all gid this user is associated.

This isn't possible, or even meaningful, in the kernel.

The relationship between UIDs and GIDs is managed by userspace. A process with a given UID will typically have the GIDs specified by `/etc/group`, but **may** have a different set of GIDs depending on how it was launched.

If you need to do authentication based on GID (which sounds a little questionable, but I'll let it slide), you need to look at the list of GIDs associated with the specific process that you're trying to authenticate. There's no way to get back to that information from a UID.